# Simple JSP deployment ( 404 - Not Found ) on Wildfly Server

Tags: jsp, servlet-3.0, wildfly-9, eclipse-jee

i faced issue while i'm trying to test the deployment of JSP on `wildfly-9` Server, its say `404-Not Found` while the Same JSP work fine on `Tomcat server`.
same problem happen for both JSP/Servlet while deployment !!!

```
the Problem look in configuring the [ wildfly-9 ] server.
```

Comment: I am not able to understand your problem completely but I think that link (https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY9/Application+deployment) may help you.

Comment: What is the URL you're trying? You may want to check the context name.